# Deep Link Doesn't Work on Instragram Story Swipe Up

Tags: android, mobile, instagram, mobile-website, android-deep-link

I have a deep link to our Android app. The link is working correct when I click it on from Slack, Whatsapp, or something like these apps. But, It doesn't work on Instagram Story Swipe Up feature. It opens their browser when I swipe up and I see the page on our mobile web site.

What's the problem?